# Convert CSOM to JSOM easily?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom, sharepoint-clientobject, sharepoint-jsom

is it possible to convert or migrate easily a C# written web service from CSOM to the JavaScript object model JSOM?

I think its mostly the "same" - except few things which are really really different.

Maybe there is a tool for it or you have great ideas for this.
Or maybe there is an guide for this?

Thank's in advance for any idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tool for converting **CSOM** to **JSOM**. But you will find all equivalents API of **CSOM** in **JSOM**. For Example, your using **[AttachmentCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.attachmentcollection.aspx)** in **CSOM**, so equivalent of `AttachmentCollection` is **[SP.AttachmentCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245160.aspx)** in **JSOM**. So you can just start by *FIND* and *REPLACE* from following

[SharePoint 2013 .NET Server, CSOM, JSOM, and REST API index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn268594.aspx)